# Registering builtin modules when embedding Node.js?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I am currently embedding Node.js inside a C++ application. I am having trouble registering a custom module as builtin for Node.js.

The following code is what I tried (the module code is copied from the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)).

```
#include <node.h>

using v8::Exception;
using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Number;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;

// This is the implementation of the "add" method
// Input arguments are passed using the
// const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args struct
void Add(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

  // Check the number of arguments passed.
  if (args.Length() < 2) {
    // Throw an Error that is passed back to JavaScript
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong number of arguments")));
    return;
  }

  // Check the argument types
  if (!args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsNumber()) {
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong arguments")));
    return;
  }

  // Perform the operation
  double value = args[0]->NumberValue() + args[1]->NumberValue();
  Local<Number> num = Number::New(isolate, value);

  // Set the return value (using the passed in
  // FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>&)
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(num);
}

void Init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "add", Add);
}

NODE_MODULE_X(addon, Init, 0, NM_F_BUILTIN);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return node::Start(argc, argv);
}
```

As you can see, I register it via the macro `NODE_MODULE_X(addon, Init, 0, NM_F_BUILTIN)`. If you call `node::get_builtin_module("addon")` afterwards, you'll receive a pointer to the module.

However, if you then execute `require("addon")` in Node.js, an error will be thrown for module not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey @ains, I'm having the same problem.  Did you manage to find a solution to this please?

Comment: @RichardFawcett It's been a while but if I remember correctly, to access your addon that was registered as builtin, you need to do `process.binding('addon')` instead. Feel free to post it as answer if you can verify it. Thanks.